# How to send Billing information with Stripe token for validation checks

Tags: stripe-payments

I have got a stripe token from stripe js, Now I want to charge the customer. How do I send the billing address along with the stripe token for charging. My objective is to validate zip code and address_line1 which I have enabled at the stripe dashboard.

**Note:**- I can send the billing info without using a stripe token, by using the card details entered. I want to do it using the token received. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution is to send the billing address details when creating the token with Stripe.js This is covered in the [createToken()](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js#card-createToken) documentation where it lists all the fields you can provide.

Otherwise, you would save the card on a customer first and then use the [Update Card API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_card) on the server to provide the billing address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But the token creation will not fail if wrong billing address is provided.

Comment: there's no way to have the token creation fail at that point it can only happen when creating a charge or the customer.